# How to avoid thumbnail of the console screen in vmware web client?

Tags: security, virtualization

I want to avoid that the anyone can spy the thumbnail console. Anyone knows how to do it? 
Thanks

[VMWare Remote Client Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIbqM.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screen thumbnail is only visible to users who have the Virtual Machine > Interaction > Console Interaction privilege.

In other words, if you don't have the permissions to open the VM's console, you won't see the thumbnail (it will show up as a sort of "broken image").

Organize your sensitive VMs in folders and assign Roles in such a way that only the operators that need to have the Console Interaction privilege. You may have to create a new role for that and make sure the above-mentioned privilege is disabled for that role.

Comment: Then, Is not possible to restrict the administrator to see the console?

Comment: Being able to see the console is not a restriction. Please rephrase the question. You can't separate the two: you have permissions for the console and the thumbnail, or you don't. Both are controlled by the same privilege.